# Safari evaluating code it shoudn't : TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, safari

My code has two modes. Depending on the mode, `data_holder` can be very different.

I have the following code.

```
if (mode == 1) {
    trials[i]['material'][k]['named'] = data_holder[a]['segmentation']['named']
// more stuff that works fine.          

} else if (mode == 2) {
    // more stuff that works fine
```

}

I'm testing on both Chrome and Safari. It works fine in Chrome, for both modes. 
Mode 1 works in safari as well, but mode 2 raises the following error. Strangly, the error raised is not in the part that should be executed.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'data_holder[a]['segmentation']')

Why is it evaluating data_holder[a]['segmentation'] when it's not supposed to be in that section of the if-statement?

Comment: Please fix the formatting and provide sample input. It would also help if you insert it as a runnable snippet. Where is *data_holder* defined or assigned a value? What is its value? Why aren't the variables declared?

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the most essential parts that reproduce the error?

Comment: @ハセン It is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting this code in Safari console, it works fine:

```
trials = []
data_holder = {}
mode = 2

if (mode == 1) {
    trials[i]['material'][k]['named'] = data_holder[a]['segmentation']['named']
// more stuff that works fine.          

} else if (mode == 2) {
    // more stuff that works fine
    console.log("safe");
}
```

Probably something else is happening that's causing mode not to be set to 2 as you expect.